# kafka enable default round robbin partition-er

Tags: java, apache-kafka

In my one of the application I need to employ a Round Robbin key partitioning strategy on my kafka producer.

Writing to different partition works only with below settings **(1)**:

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, MyRandomPartioner.class);
```

And the `MyRandomPartitioner` Class is implemented as follows:

```
public class MyRandomPartioner implements Partitioner {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyRandomPartitioner.class);

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs) {
    }

    @Override
    public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] keyBytes, Object value, byte[] valueBytes, Cluster cluster) {
        List<PartitionInfo> partitions = cluster.partitionsForTopic(topic);
        int numPartitions = partitions.size();
        logger.info(" Partition of Topic :" + numPartitions);
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(4) + 1;
            logger.info(" selected Partition of Topic :" + randomInt);
            return  randomInt;

    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

}
```

Since I want to have equal distribution I disabled the above props **(1)** then it always writing to single partition.

My producer code:

```
void sendData(String operation, String message){
final ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(producerKafkaConfig.getTopicName(), operation,message);
            producer.send(record, new ProducerCallback()); 
        }
//Here operation is always fixed and message is my actual content.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your records are key and value, default partitioner will check for key,  if key is not there then only it will do normal partitioning otherwise hash will be calculated based on key.

Incase of key can not be removed for you records you can use the below partitioner code

```
public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] keyBytes, Object value, byte[] 

    valueBytes, Cluster cluster) {
            List<PartitionInfo> partitions = cluster.partitionsForTopic(topic);
            int numPartitions = partitions.size();

            int nextValue = nextValue(topic);
            List<PartitionInfo> availablePartitions = cluster.availablePartitionsForTopic(topic);
            if (availablePartitions.size() > 0) {
                int part = Utils.toPositive(nextValue) % availablePartitions.size();
                return availablePartitions.get(part).partition();
            } else {
                // no partitions are available, give a non-available partition
                return Utils.toPositive(nextValue) % numPartitions;
            }

        }
```